# Kendo tabs strange behaviour

Tags: kendo-ui, tabs, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC/Kendo, I have a series of tabs like so:

[image]

However when I add an icon to the emailing tab a bar appears under all the other tabs:

[image]

Could anyone advise as to why this would happen?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So I have provided a sample Dojo for you which should hopefully help https://dojo.telerik.com/OsIhINOy/4

What I suspect is happening is that you are not applying the `k-state-active` to the selected tab when clicked which is why the line is still appearing. (you can see this by just deleting the `k-state-active` class from the first tab.

If you are able to provide a sample of your code in the future it will help in assisting your question better rather than images as it is difficult to tell what may be happening from just an image.